# Get response from iframe

Tags: php, jquery, api, iframe

I am using Calendy integration on my jQuery. I am using a button to open a popup. In that popup we have `iframe` in which we have multiple steps. In each step an API URL is hit. I can see those API responses in the console, but I need to get it in my variable and send it to my server and save it in to my database.

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="interview-booking-button" role="button" class="btn btn-label-warning btn-bold btn-elevate btn-elevate-air btn-sm btn-icon-h my-1 my-md-0" onclick="initCalendyInterview()">
  <i class="flaticon2-group"></i>
  Set Interview Booking
</a>
```

```js
window.initCalendyInterview = function (name, email) {
  Calendly.initPopupWidget({url: 'my calendy url'}).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
  return false;
}
```

This function shows a popup which contains an `iframe` and in the `iframe` URL is opened and 2-3 steps are performed, where some API is hit. I want the response of last API hit in my current page.

I am confused how we can get the response from the API which is called inside the `iframe` (on a different url).

Please help me. I have tried the event listener as follows but did not get the response of the APIs:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: `get the response from the API which is called inside the iframe (on a different url).` if the content of the iframe is on a different URL to the parent window then what you're trying to do is not possible, for various security reasons

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I need it from third party integration, which is providing the their own UI with form integration as per the apis. But the response in those apis I need to save the response in my Database.

Comment: Is it not possible to get the api response by any eventListener?

Comment: You can not subscribe to anything happening _inside_ the iframe - content from different domain, means Same Origin Policy prevents you from getting any access to the elements inside the iframe. What you have shown is subscribing to `postMessage` events, that would work (because those are meant for cross-domain communication) - but of course it depends on whether those APIs _send_ any such messages to begin with.